# xcode: Empty project with WKPicker causes libc++abi.dylib NSException

Tags: ios, xcode

```
2015-08-17 06:18:50.281 testcrash WatchKit Extension[1050:29694] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<InterfaceController 0x7d248f80> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key (null).'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02f882c4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00682df4 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02f87ee1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x002c4696 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x00205870 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 105
    5   Foundation                          0x002057ff -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 288
    6   WatchKit                            0x0014d454 __48-[SPRemoteInterface handlePlist:fromIdentifier:]_block_invoke905 + 46
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03db8837 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03dd641d _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x03dbf0da _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 689
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x02eda46e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x02e981e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2356
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x02e975f6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02e9740b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    14  Foundation                          0x00241e11 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
    15  Foundation                          0x002e7f6d -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 82
    16  libxpc.dylib                        0x040d30c7 _xpc_objc_main + 486
    17  libxpc.dylib                        0x040d5e26 xpc_main + 215
    18  Foundation                          0x00410fb5 service_connection_handler + 0
    19  PlugInKit                           0x02e001f4 -[PKService run] + 582
    20  WatchKit                            0x00171509 main + 146
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x03dfbae1 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I get this crash with a clean, new project. Drag an WKPicker into the storyboard and try to simulate the program.

(native watchos2 app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here seems to be the picker stays empty.

```
var foodList: [(String, String)] = [
    ("Broccoli", "Gross"),
    ("Brussel Sprouts", "Gross"),
    ("Soup", "Delicious"),
    ("Steak", "Delicious"),
    ("Ramen", "Delicious"),
    ("Pizza", "Delicious") ]

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
    let pickerItems: [WKPickerItem] = foodList.map {
        let pickerItem = WKPickerItem()
        pickerItem.title = $0.0
        pickerItem.caption = $0.1
        return pickerItem
    }
    serverPicker.setItems(pickerItems)
}
```

Resolves that problem.

Copied from: http://www.sneakycrab.com/blog/2015/6/12/wkinterfacepicker-in-watchkit-20-using-the-digital-crown